# Firebase role based access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to restrict access to write some documents.
Therefore I created an "administrators" collection which uses the UID of the user as document uid and the a property "admin" to have a value to check against.

The database rule i'm currently trying to implement is this one:

```
  match /approved-posts/{post} {
        allow read: if true
        allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/administrators/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
  }
```

My uid is: **uYdyhMBAgyZ36ZNF5B2iPb0NdxQ2**

So I have the following collection in firebase:
[image: firebase collection image]

But somehow when I try to create a new post I get the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:158627:28)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Adding semicolons at the end of the lines (e.g. allow read: if true;) didn't help.

When using the simulator I get an null value error:

[image: Null value error]

I read https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions and tried a simpler rule. But still I get an error.
[image: check if document exists rule]

Is there any setting maybe which I have to turn on?

Answer (score 1):

Your rules looks perfectly fine, but you are missing semi-colon at the end of read and write rule, Not sure if this is the solution, but try adding semi-colon and update the rule.

```
  match /approved-posts/{post} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/administrators/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh no my UID was false. 
It had a space at the beginning. So I had a copy paste error.

Because of the trimming at the dashboard I haven't noticed. Only after I recreated a document with a UID without having a leading space it works fine.

Thanks for your help so far :)